# Axios get request works but post request returns callFunctionReturnedFlushedQueue and Network Error

Tags: react-native, clojure, axios

I'm calling a route with axios that I want to really call as a post request. However, when calling with a post request like so:

```
export const uploadFeatured = (mediaName, youtubeLink, description) => async dispatch => {
    console.log("uploading", mediaName, youtubeLink, description);
    const res = await axios.post(domain + '/api/uploadFeatured');
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
rror: Request failed with status code 403
createError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:156601:26
settle@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:156591:25
handleLoad@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:156491:15
dispatchEvent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:33005:31
setReadyState@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:32074:27
__didCompleteResponse@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:31905:29
emit@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7758:42
__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3387:36
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3119:31
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3341:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3118:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

However, get request works without any error. Here's my clojure code for the routes and the server for request handling:

```
(ns humboiserver.routes.home
  (:require
   [humboiserver.layout :as layout]
   [clojure.java.io :as io]
   [humboiserver.middleware :as middleware]
   [ring.util.response]
   [ring.util.http-response :as response]
   [humboiserver.routes.featured :as featured]))

(defn home-page [request]
  (layout/render request "home.html" {:docs (-> "docs/docs.md" io/resource slurp)}))

(defn about-page [request]
  (layout/render request "about.html"))

(defn home-routes []
  [""
   {:middleware [middleware/wrap-csrf
                 middleware/wrap-formats]}
   ["/" {:get home-page}]
   ["/api"
    ["/about" {:get about-page}]
    ["/featured" featured/get-featured]
    ["/invest" featured/invest]
    ["/connect" featured/connect]
    ["/uploadFeatured" featured/upload-featured]]])
```

and

```
(defn response [data & [status]]
  {:status (or status 200)
   :headers {"Content-Type" "application/edn"
             "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type"
             "Access-Control-Request-Method" "GET, OPTIONS, POST"
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
             "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" true
             }
   :body (generate-string data)})


(defn upload-featured [req]
  (prn "request is " (:params req))
  ;;(db/insert "featured" (:params req))
  (response "uploaded")
  )
```

How to fix this error and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are getting a "forbidden" error. Are you running your Axios request from a JS page served from the same server? Note that you specify only "GET, OPTIONS" in the Access-Control-Request-Method.

Comment: specifying post doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting a 403 Forbidden response when POST-ing, GET is fine, but POST seems to be forbidden. When the server/client do not run on the same host/origin, some CORS restrictions may apply. Somewhere you define response headers:

```
"Access-Control-Request-Method" "GET, OPTIONS"
```

Maybe adding 'POST' to this response header might resolve the situation.

Comment: Adding POST to the header doesn't resolve the error

Comment: In the axios post here `const res = await axios.post(domain + '/api/uploadFeatured');` you perform a post but don't supply any post data, maybe that is of influence?

Comment: adding data doesn't resolve the issue either

Comment: have you tried to check if any session/authentication cookies are required? Perhaps tell axios to send credentials: `const res = await axios.post(domain + '/api/uploadFeatured', data, { withCredentials: true })`